# R Frequency Table - Splitting a Column into 2 different columns

Tags: r, frequency

I am trying to create a frequency table using the data from Kaggle - Loan_Data.  Below is the code I used and what I ultimately wanted to see using R.  I am not sure if it is relevant or not, but I am using the cloud service for R.

> Create Frequency Table for Purpose

```
counts <- loan_data %>%
group_by(purpose) %>%
summarise(counts = n())
colnames(counts)[2]<-'total_n'    
View(counts)
```

| purpose | total_n |
| --- | --- |
| all_other | 2331 |
| credit_card | 1262 |
| debt_consolidation | 3957 |
| educational | 343 |
| home_improvement | 629 |
| major_purchase | 437 |
| small_business | 619 |

This is fine.  The next part is where I am running into a issue

> Divide total_n to showcase Accepted and Denied Credit Policy

```
counts.purpose1 <- loan_data %>%
          group_by(purpose, credit.policy) %>%
         dplyr::summarise(freq = n())
```

This chunk gives the following table which is correct but not the way I want the table to look like:

| purpose | credit.policy | freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| all_other | Accepted | 1835 |
| all_other | Denied | 496 |
| credit_card | Accepted | 1020 |
| credit_card | Denied | 242 |
| debt_consolidation | Accepted | 3223 |
| debt_consolidation | Denied | 734 |
| educational | Accepted | 254 |
| educational | Denied | 89 |
| home_improvement | Accepted | 512 |
| home_improvement | Denied | 117 |
| major_purchase | Accepted | 371 |
| major_purchase | Denied | 66 |
| small_business | Accepted | 495 |
| small_business | Denied | 124 |

Instead I want the table to look like the following:

| purpose | total_n | Accepted | Denied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| all_other | 2331 | 1835 | 496 |
| credit_card | 1262 | 1020 | 242 |
| debt_consolidation | 3957 | 3223 | 734 |
| education | 343 | 254 | 89 |
| home_improvement | 629 | 512 | 117 |
| major_purchase | 437 | 371 | 66 |
| small_business | 619 | 495 | 124 |

Is this possible by changing the way I create my frequency table? Or is it easier to just use this a basis and just manually create a df to make the table that I want?

I have tried this thinking it may work:

```
 counts.purpose1 %>%
      group_by(purpose) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(credit.policy = n(),
                accepted = n('Accepted'),
                denied = n('Denied'))
```

but this is the error it gives me:

Error in `dplyr::summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `accepted = n("Accepted")`.
ℹ In group 1: `purpose = "all_other"`.
Caused by error in `n()`:
! unused argument ("Accepted")
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to first split `credit.policy` into two columns `Accepted` and `Denied` using `pivot_wider()`, then create `total_n` using `mutate()` by each purpose and relocating `total_n` in the second column using `.before=` argument:

```
library(tidyverse)

counts.purpose1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "credit.policy", values_from = "freq") %>%
                    group_by(purpose) %>%
                    mutate(total_n = sum(Accepted , Denied),.before = 2) 


# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Groups:   purpose [7]
  purpose            total_n Accepted Denied
  <chr>                <int>    <int>  <int>
1 all_other             2331     1835    496
2 credit_card           1262     1020    242
3 debt_consolidation    3957     3223    734
4 educational            343      254     89
5 home_improvement       629      512    117
6 major_purchase         437      371     66
7 small_business         619      495    124
```